# Stop CSS Transition on Load + Reverse Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a transition to bring a hidden edit menu on hover of a div (which you would be editting). Unfortunately, I've had two dueling problems that seem to be piggy-backing on each other. I want a small animation to fire on hover, then reverse when the hover is gone. I've gotten that to work, but no matter what I do, the reverse animation fires on page load. I've tried some of the other things suggested such as a preload styling that stops animation until page load then it's removed but it doesn't seem to stop anything at all.

If I try to, say, add the animation css to .editMenu with jquery after page load, that just makes everything else. Is it something in my code that's not letting the above stackOverflow option work?

I've crafted a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaGNXW of my basic code.

```
animation: .1s fadeOut ease-out;
```

This is the bit of code that is causing all of the issue. The codepen is a bit frustrating because if you refresh it doesn't show the page-load issue, but in a normal HTML file it does.

This was marked as a duplicate, however, the answers within that question do not solve my issue. It currently will continue to fire regardless of the whole 'add class remove class' suggestion, so I do not believe that code is similar enough that it will function in the same manner.

Comment: Note that this functionality is not touch friendly.

Comment: This is a bit of my first venture into CSS animations (and fallbacks) -- how do you make something like this touch friendly?

Comment: You can't technically hover on touch devices. You would need something on the screen to imply a user should "touch here" to show your buttons, then handle a "click" event to do the same thing as your hover.
If this is an app (with Phonegap or something), you have the option to do a touch-and-hold feature but, in a web browser, users don't expect this functionality.

Comment: That's very true. This is a desktop site that will be used on tablets as well, so I'll look into how I can replicate it with touch events when it's gone mobile. Thank you! ...Now if I can just get the original problem fixed, I'll be all set. ^_^

Comment: Also, I've read that you can just add `:focus` and/or `:active` pseudo classes to your CSS to handle this.

Comment: Mmm I gave that a quick shot, but no luck.

`&:hover > .editMenu, &:focus > .editMenu, &:active > .editMenu{
        animation: .1s fadeIn ease-out;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }`

Comment: I hate to play devil's advocate here, but I'd think twice before you take a foray into CSS animations, especially for anything that requires complex timelining (like the reversing you're talking about). Javascript is far better equipped to achieve this, moreover using a [library like GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) ensures browser compatibility (do away with that modernizr fallback!), and does groovy stuff like push transitions to the GPU automagically for smoothness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, more a word of advice.

After **extensive** use of CSS for creating complex animations and multi-layered transitions, if you ask me, you should think twice before dedicating any more time learning this workflow. The drawbacks (compatibility issues *especially* for mobile, annoying-but-neccessary prefixing, terrible timelining & ZERO debugging ability) are not worth the trouble.

Here is the article that, for me, completely opened my eyes to the power of JS when animating - and that means animating *anything*, something which CSS cannot do by a long way:

[Myth Busting: CSS Animations vs. JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)

Some of the main strengths of js the article mentions:

- Independent scale/rotation/position control
- Offloading calculations to a different thread
- Runtime controls and events (reversing, pausing and playing animations, slowmo etc.)
- Cross-browser compatibility & auto-prefixing CSS

The list goes on and on. If you're thinking about getting into animation, then I urge you to use a javascript library like GSAP. Anything that works is great, but DEFINITELY NOT THE JQUERY ANIMATE FUNCTION. It is around 10x slower than, for instance, both CSS animations and GSAP. You should **never** use it.

Ultimately, I was able to do what your CSS animations could do in this much JS:

```
var section = document.querySelector(".section");
section.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e){
    TweenLite.to(".editMenu", 0.1, {scale: 1, alpha: 1, x: -20, y: 10});
});

section.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e){
    TweenLite.to(".editMenu", 0.1, {scale: 0.7, alpha: 0, x: 0, y: 0});
});
```

And, naturally, far less CSS. At the end of the day, CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet - great for styling, not so much for animations; so isolate relevant control to technologies better suited to handle that control. You'll have a much better time that way. :)

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot. Thank you much! See how it works out!